# How to replace highlighted/conditionally formatted cells with a value in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, find-and-replace, conditional-formatting

I am trying to sort through some questionnaire data for my dissertation. There are over 700 open-ended answers for each question, so am trying to speed things up a bit.

Background to my issue: I have all answers to a specific questionnaire question in one column. I have highlighted cells which contain certain kinds of text in order to see who has responded similarly: e.g. for the question 'What is important in your life', I have highlighted all answers in the column which contain the word 'love'. I have done this with conditional formatting.

My issue: What I'd really like to do is replace these cells with the value '1' and all of the other cells, not containing the word 'love', and therefore not highlighted, with '0'. Is there anyway of doing this?

Thank you already in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new column B near the first one A and write the following:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("love",A2,1)),1,0)`

A2 the first answer in the column, write the above formula in B2 and you can drag it down
write `love` the same way as in the answer

Comment: @Lau, if this resolved your issue, please mark it as the correct answer.